# How to restart the fragment in viewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I want to restart the fragment, i.e. recall the onCreate and onCreateView method of fragment when refresh button ia clicked. How to achieve it?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Why not create methods that does your _refresh_ and then call those methods when refresh is clicked.

Answer (score 5):

The answer probably lies in the `getItemPosition()` method of your `ViewPager` adapter. To quote from the [Android Developers blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html):

> If you’re trying to replace Views in your ViewPager, it isn’t enough
>   just to change the data set behind the adapter and call
>   notifyDataSetChanged(). You also need to ensure that you’ve correctly
>   implemented getItemPosition(Object object) and return POSITION_NONE
>   for items that have changed and return POSITION_UNCHANGED or the
>   actual position for items that haven’t changed.

If you call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on your adapter, and your `getItemPosition()` is set to:

```
@Override
public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
    return PagerAdapter.POSITION_NONE;
}
```

Then every fragment will be re-created from scratch.